# Can I combine a using() {} block with a method's out parameter?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, using-statement

Given a method

```
public static bool Connection.TryCreate(out Connection connection) {}
```

And a piece of calling code:

```
Connection connection;
if (!Connection.TryCreate(out connection))
    // handle failure gracefully.

/*
 * work with connection
 *
 * …
 *
 */

connection.Dispose();
```

I'm using the same pattern as `bool.TryParse` and friends, i.e. `TryCreate` returns whether the operation was successful.

I realize the `using()` variable needs to be read-only within its block, but is there a way to turn the above into a `using() {}` block (`TryCreate` only sets it once), like so:

```
using (Connection connection)
{
    if (!Connection.TryCreate(out connection))
        // this would leave the using() block prematurely

    /*
     * work with sconnection
     *
     * …
     *
     */
}
```

(This doesn't compile:

> error CS1657: Cannot pass 'connection' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'using variable'

)

Comment: Did you do a simple test with NULL/non-NULL values for `connection` already? Did it compile? Did it run?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have mentioned that my fictitious example wouldn't compile. I've amended the post accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

No, that is not possible.

The `using (x) {...}` construct makes a copy of `x` when it enters the block, so you can do this:

```
var x = new FileStream(...);
using (x)
{
    x = null;
}
```

The stream will still be disposed when the `using` block ends.

The corollary is that this won't work either:

```
Stream x = null;
using (x)
{
    x = new FileStream(...);
}
```

here the stream you construct inside the using block will not be disposed.

What you can do, however, is this:

```
Connection connection;
if (Connection.TryCreate(out connection))
    using (connection)
    {
    }
```

In C# 7.0 and onwards you can combine this with "out variables" to form:

```
if (Connection.TryCreate(out var connection))
    using (connection)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bad use of the `Try*` pattern (some would argue this is an *anti-pattern*).

Instead of a `TryCreate`, just have a `Create` method that throws an exception if not successful and that returns the created connection.

Then you could do the usual:

```
using(Connection connection = Connection.Create())
{
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid an exception being thrown and the required `try{}catch{}`, have the `Create` method return `null` when a connection could not be created and test for that.

Comment: Arguably, a TryCreate that sometimes returns null would also serve

Comment: @MarcGravell - Possibly. But the semantics of `Try*` (at least in the BCL) would be to return a success boolean. Or do you mean the `out` parameter?

Comment: I don't see how this is any different than using `bool.TryParse()` over `bool.Create()`, or Uri.TryCreate over `new Uri()`. It avoids dealing with exceptions, which may sometimes be desirable.

Comment: I meant a regular return, non-null on success, else null

Comment: ↑↑↑ It *does* return success (or failure, as the case may be).

Comment: @MarcGravell - Absolutely agree - returning a `null` is a good alternative.

Comment: @Oded - I assumed that is what it did when I wrote my wrong answer -- This is because the `Try*` used in Parse does not make sense for a Create operation IMHO.

Comment: @Hogan - I agree, which is why my answer steers clear from a `Try` method.

Comment: Having a factory "try" method is entirely reasonable.  The all-to-common pattern of having a "try" method return the created object as an out-reference parameter, however, seems much more dubious. An interface `IVehicleFactory<T>` which defines a method `bool TryBuildCarToSpecs(CarSpects theSpecs, out T result)` can only be used by code that wants to build something of precise type T. By contrast, if the function were e.g. `T TryBuildCarToSpecs(CarSpecs theSpecs, ref BuildProblemReport faults)` the interface could be declared covariant, and code which wanted an `IVehicleFactory<Car>` could...

Comment: ...perfectly happily accept an `IVehicleVactory<ToyotaCamryHatchback>` without any problem.  If the factory is returning a class type, and if no problem indication is needed beyond pass/fail, one could leave off the 'faults' parameter and simply return 'null' in the problem case.  If the factory produces something that's possibly a value type, but pass/fail reporting is adequate, the 'ref' parameter could be of type 'bool.'

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
Connection connection;
if (Connection.TryCreate(out connection))
{
    using (connection)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

But it might be better if you just returned `null` on failure:

```
using (Connection connection = Connection.Create())
{
    if (connection != null)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

The `finally` block that is created by the `using` checks whether `connection` is `null` and doesn't do anything if it is.

Also, if you're not declaring the variable in the `using`, then it doesn't have to be read-only.

Comment: From MSDN - [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx): `You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, but this is not a best practice.`

Comment: Yeah, but I think it's the best solution, if you don't want to modify `TryCreate()` for some reason.

Comment: What happens when TryCreate fails?

Comment: @Hogan, I forgot about that at first. The necessary `if` is there now.

Comment: That compiles, but does it really guarantee that the resources are cleaned up in all cases?

Comment: I'll accept the answer — the first part, that is. The second part seems bad in that, if connection *does* end up being `null`, the code would silently do nothing, and I wouldn't even be able to check for `null` since the block would never get entered.

Comment: @SörenKuklau, of course not. [There are several corner cases when `using` doesn't call `Dispose()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595372/is-there-a-situation-in-which-dispose-wont-be-called-for-a-using-block), like a power failure or uncatchable exception. But I think the only thing that can happen here (except for the corner cases) is something like `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: @SörenKuklau, in the second case, if you want to react to failure, just add `else` to the `if`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. So it *does* enter the `using` block, but with a null object. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you are concerned about exceptions in the gap between a method call and the using, you could use try/finally:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    if(!conn.TryCreate(out conn)) return;
    ...
} finally {
    if(conn != null) conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Sure, but that's pretty much a re-implementation of `using`'s syntactic sugar. :) I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

A step sideways ?

```
public class ConnectTo : IDisposable
{

  public Connection CurrentConnection {get; private set;}

  public ConnectTo()
  {
    CurrentConnection = null;
    // Connect up to whatever.
  }


  #region IDisposable

  // Blah blah

  #endregion
}
```

then

```
using( ConnectedTo conn = new ConnectTo())
{
  if (conn.CurrentConnection != null)
  {
    //Do Stuff
  }
}
```